# Can I exclude folders in a 301 redirect so that it only affects part of the web?

Tags: redirect, seo

I have a question about applying redirects excluding some folders. Here you have my case:

My domain example.com is published in several languages:

```
example.com/es for content in spanish
example.com/it for content in italian
example.com/en for content in english
```

In my old website example.com/ the English content was under "/" (in the root of the project) but now it has been migrated to example.com/en leaving "/" without any content.

I want to apply a rule that all the content in English, indexed by Google hosted under example.com/ go to example.com/en but **without this affecting the content** under the other languages.

`example.com/content1` redirected to `example.com/en/content1`

but mantaining unaltered:

```
example.com/es/content1es
example.com/it/content1it
...
```

That is, as indicated at the beginning, **excluding the language folders and their child content**. Is this possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: It should be possible, but we can't give you a solution without knowing more about your situation.   The implementation would be very different for different web servers, operating systems, and content management systems.   Which of each of those are you using?

Comment: Once you clarify your question, you might want to consider asking it on [webmasters.se].   While this is somewhat programming related, it is much more likely to get better answers on webmasters.

Comment: Note that, on the web, these are "directories" and not "folders" which is a Windows operating system concept and not the same thing.